# lecture slide about AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, pseudocode

Below is a lecture slide about AI. I think it's a pseudo code about something.
But I don't know what these symbols mean. I even can't get the main points of this slide.
Please help me. Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: could you post a link to this presentation?

Comment: http://videolectures.net/ssll09_rintanen_aip/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pseudocode.  Please check out Norvig and Russell, "Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach".  This looks like effects of an action for a reflex agent but you need at least the previous slide and probably the previous few slides to determine that.  It could also deal with the frame problem in some way.

At any rate, presumably given an action with a precondition p and an effect e and a state s, the set of effects are the four logic statements: x , not x, x and not x.  The first two logic statements say x when x has the value 1 in the effect e, etc.  The third and fourth logic statements say x if in the set of logic clauses phi then x has the value 1 in effect e and the state s entails (|=) the set of logic clauses phi.

So a pair precondition,effect is executable in a state s if and only if s entails p and the set of effects in s is consistent.

But as I said more information is actually needed.